# CakePHP - Access table from inside a tab

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp, tabs, html-table

My page has 4 tabs, inside each tabs there is a table, and i want to be able to paint the rows of a table inside certain tab.
Right now my code paint the row of all the tables, not just one table.
I have tried variations of the same line of code, but cant find the right code to access just one table.

In every tab there is a table with a different id, and i dont know how to access each table separately according to what i need. The last part of my code has a condition, and in every condition the line is different. They should be the same but i changed them to try to access a table, but i cant find the way.

Maybe you know the correct code of that line.

Thanks.

My code page.ctp:

```
<div id="tab-1">
    <table id="tablesc">
    ...//samefor all
    </div>

<div id="tab-2">
    <table id="tablesd">
    ...//samefor all
    </div>
<div id="tab-3">
<table id="tablespr">
...//samefor all
</div>
<div id="tabs-4">
<table id="tablespr">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Codigo</th>
        <th colspan="2">Criterio</th>
    </tr>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create($file); ?>
    <?php $j=1; ?>
    <?php $indice = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($xmlrecibidoSPR->entryresult as $entry):?>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%"><?php echo $entry->codigo; ?></td>
        <?php $etapa = '14';?>
        <td colspan="2"><?php echo $this->Form->input('criteriosSPR' . $j, array('options' => $opcionescriterios, 'label' => "", 'onchange' => 'cambio2(' . $indice . ', ' . $entry->resultnumber . ', ' . $etapa . ', ' . '\'' . $carpeta . '\'' . ', \'tablaspr\')')); ?></td>            
        </tr>       
    <?php ++$j; ?>
        <?php ++$indice; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
</div>
```

My code custom.js:

```
function change(indicetabla, indicexml, etapa, carpeta, tabla){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "../webroot/files/pjs15/results.xml", false);
    xhttp.send();
    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;/* xml */
    var documento = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];
    var sufijo = "";
    if(etapa == 11 || etapa == 21){
        sufijo = "scp";
       } else if(etapa == 12 || etapa == 22){
        sufijo = "sd";
       } else if(etapa == 13 || etapa == 23){ 
        sufijo = "ieee";
       } else if(etapa == 14 || etapa == 24) {
        sufijo = "spr";
       } else{
        sufijo = "";
       }
    var table = document.getElementById(tabla);
        var t = document.getElementById("criterios" + sufijo +indicetabla);
    var selectedText = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;

    $.ajax({
        url:'../webroot/js/ajax.php',
        method:'get',
        data:{name:indicexml, criterio:selectedText, etapa:etapa, carpeta:carpeta},
        success:function(data)
        {
            particula = selectedText.substr(0,2);
            if(particula=='CI')/* indicexml */
            {
                $("table").find('tr:eq(' + indicetabla + ')').css('background-color', '#98ff98');//mint
            }
            else if(particula=='CE')
            {
                document.getElementById("table").find('tr:eq(' + indicetabla + ')').css('background-color', '#f6b8b8');//powder pink
            }
            else
            {
                $("table" + sufijo).find('tr:eq(' + indicetabla + ')').css('background-color', '#fcf8e3');
            }
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery id selectors](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) must begin with a `#` sign.

You are concatenating "table" with each unique suffix here, but need to prefix the selector with `#`.

```
$("table" + sufijo).find('tr:eq(' + indicetabla + ')').css('background-color', '#fcf8e3');
```

Should be

```
$("#table" + sufijo).find('tr:eq(' + indicetabla + ')').css('background-color', '#fcf8e3');
```